# Location of Recorded Audio of Keynote Presentation on OSX

Tags: macos, audio, iwork-keynote

So, as you may or may not know, you can record yourself as you give a Keynote presentation and play it back later. You can export the presentation to a movie and then you get the audio on top of slides that were actually shown as the slideshow was happening.

Unfortunately, Keynote crashes for me every time I try to export.

I really would like the audio. Does anybody know where the audio is saved to?

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

1. Open your Keynote presentation.
2. Open a Finder window, then press shift+command+G. This will have an input for your file.
3. At the top of your Keynote window, there is an icon to the left of the file name for your presentation. Click and hold until it's selected.
4. Then drag to the input box in Finder. The Keynote location should be pasted.
5. Click "Go."
6. Right-click your Keynote file, and click "Show Package Contents."
7. Then open the Data folder. There should be a file called "MovieRecording-XXXXXXXXX.mov". That's the audio recording for your presentation.

Comment: This no longer works in the latest version of Keynote. New files are binary encoded and the audio and video recordings are encased in the presentation file.